# Waiting time in M/M/n queue

Tags: queuing-theory, sensitivity-analysis

I was able to numerically "show" that an M/M/n queue is concave increasing in the number for $n$ servers, which makes intuitive sense. However is there a formal analytical proof for it? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dyer and Proll (1977)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/mnsc.23.9.1019)<sup>1</sup> showed that for an *M/M/c* queue, the mean waiting time is a strictly decreasing and convex function of *c*.

---

<sub>Reference</sub>

<sub>[1] Dyer, M. E., Proll, L. G. (1977). On the Validity of Marginal Analysis for Allocating Servers in *M/M/c* Queues. *Management Science.* 23(9):1019-1022.</sub>

Comment: For a broader overview see [Yu *et al.* (2006)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/probability-in-the-engineering-and-informational-sciences/article/abs/monotonicity-and-convexity-of-some-functions-associated-with-denumerable-markov-chains-and-their-applications-to-queuing-systems/8DEBEE47659A6E91E2B27C56A87362C0).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The Yu et al link has deprecated.

Comment: @Galen I've edited the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive them from the balance equations. If you check Taha's or Lieberman's Introduction to OR books, you can find the proofs.